# Is there no continuation action "ContinueWithOnMainThread" in 6.12.0 unity sdk?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore latest sdk "6.12.0" on unity. I've to get the data from the database and save it to PlayerPrefs but because PlayerPrefs only run on the main thread, it is causing an error to go with older "ContinueWith" continuation action.

Firebase has given this "ContinueWithOnMainThread" in the doc but I'm unable to find it on API. I only get the option of "ContinueWith".

What's the issue, does "ContinueWithOnMainThread" exist in 6.12.0?

Comment: Can you just not use Dispatcher.Invoke ?

Comment: @sommmen Sorry I didn't get you.
what do you exactly mean by "not using Displatecher.Invoke?"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.8 google ;)

Comment: @sommmen thanks for sharing this but nothing was getting invoked on my end perhaps something in the firebase API which I can't control or change. That's why I asked you "what do you exactly mean ... " :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bad...

Actually, You have to use **Firebase.Extensions** API to get the "ContinueWithOnMainThread" function:

```cs
using Firebase.Extensions;

void Start(){
  Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()
    .ContinueWithOnMainThread(fixTask=>{
      Debug.Log("we are in main thread");
    })
}
```

[The documentation is also available.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/extensions)

Comment: Is this api still available? When downloading Firebase for Unity there are .unitpackages for each namespace listed in your documentation link, except for Firebase.Extension.

Comment: Yes, this API gets available when you add any firebase package to the unity project