# reaching a child via LimitToLast()

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have the path up until "History" then I'm trying to reach the last child under it to get its "HRV" data.

[image]

I've used `OrderByKey().LimitByLast(1);` but I don't know how to access the "HRV" of the last child.

Code so far:

```
DatabaseReference LastHistoryEnrty = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).Child("History");

var query = LastHistoryEnrty.OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1);

var LatestHRV = query.Result.Child("HRV").GetValueAsync();
```

Comment: mind posting what you have so far with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get only a part of the resulting nodes.

You will first have to execute the query to get the entire last node, and then read its `HRV` value.

```
var query = LastHistoryEnrty.OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1);

var snapshot = query.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    // Handle the error...
  }
  else if (task.IsCompleted) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
    var LatestHRV = snapshot.Child("HRV").Value;
  }
});
```

If this means that you're transferring way more data than is needed, consider storing only the `HRV` values in a separate node and read from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm getting this error now 'Task<DataSnapshot>' does not contain a definition for 'ContinueWithOnMainThread' and no accessible extension method 'ContinueWithOnMainThread' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<DataSnapshot>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).. sorry I'm very new to ths

Comment: @ThekraSlaman Searching for "continuewithonmainthread" came up with [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61127703/1092820). Does that help?

Comment: Good to hear you made progress here @ThekraSlaman. Did you get it working between my answer and the link that Ruzihm provided?

Comment: thank you both so much! I actually used ContinueWith and it's working just fine :)!